# Safari ignoring margins when using jQuery Masonry

Tags: jquery, css, safari, jquery-masonry, percentage

I am using jquery masonry but when testing cross browser, safari has issues.

Chrome and firefox are the same, but safari looks to have little / less margins.

So i have a 2% margin for each of the masonry items which works fine when on chrome / firefox but on safari the margin is tiny.

The % does work on safari, if i say put a 20% margin it does increase the margin but only for the first item / maybe the first vertical row. On chrome / FF the margin left applies to each item.

Here is currently what i use:

```
#buildcontainer {
width: 100%;
margin-top: 6%;
}

.blogresults { 
width: 22.7%;
border: 0px solid #fff;
background-color: #fff;
margin-left: 2%;
z-index: 500;
disply: inline-block;
float:left;
}
```

I i change the margin left to e.g. 10px it works fine and applies in all browsers, it just the percentage that causes issues.

Note, the #buildcontainer is where the masonry items are held.

Comment: i wish i could, but the masonry items are dynamic and to reproduce all the layout etc would be quite a task with jsfiddle. Site is also not live so cant give an example. Sucks i know.

Comment: just increases the size of the items, as expected. Ill note this issue and come back to it

Comment: 1) i think its more an issue with jquery masonry, since if i reload safari the items are correct, until they fit into the grid and then they loose there margins.
2) my items are each their own div, should they be done as a list?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of Safari you're using, but when I checked [the plugin demo](http://masonry.desandro.com/) in an *older desktop version* of Safari, I was able to reproduce the issue. The 1% margins in each element aren't factored in when their absolute positions are calculated.

Here are a few ideas...

**Use the plugin's *gutter* option to set the horizontal space between elements**

http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#gutter

The link to the example on codepen shows how you might add this to your existing HTML/script. Since, this would apply to all browsers, you will have to adjust or remove the margins in your CSS.

**Apply a pixel margin for webkit browsers only**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .blogresults {  margin-left: 10px;   }
}
```

**Add a border to the left of your elements**
As a last resort... you could try to mimic space by adding a left border. As long as the background is not an image or a gradient, it will appear to be space.

```
.blogresults { 

   // Margin and initial border property has been removed
    width: 22.7%;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 500;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;

   // Left border has been added
    border-left: 5px solid #fff; 
}
```